# how do i efficiently test to see if a string from a list in a txt file is in another txt?

Tags: python

in the file called "`admin list.txt`" it has :

```
_Cignus_

_JustMix

_N3

_R3

_Skofy

_Surfers_

_Vxpe

0Da3s

0h_Roby

0hHaze

0hPqnos
```

And I want to see if another file called "`latest logs.txt`" with something like:

```
[21:11:29] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] mhyra wants to fight!

[21:11:30] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] ? SkyWars Solo ? Warmup started. You will be teleported in the next 10 seconds.

[21:11:33] [Client thread/FATAL]: Error executing task

[21:11:33] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] _Cignus_ wants to fight!
```

Contains ANY of the strings from the "admin list" then it prints "ALERT" if a string from "admin list" is in the last 20 lines of "`latest logs.txt`"

How would I do that?

Comment: In your latest logs.txt, there isn't any of the values from the admin list.txt, provide an example where any one of the value is present in the latest_logs.txt file based on that optimized solution can be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off by saving all of the lines from your "admin list.txt" file into a list where each line is a separate element. This way, you have a list of keywords you can iterate over and check for.

```
keywords = []
with open('admin_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    keywords = f.read().splitlines()
```

Next, you would need the last 20 lines of the "latest logs.txt". If your file is not GBs large, you can simply do:

```
logs = []
with open('latest_logs.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    logs = lines[-20:]
```

Lastly, simply check for the keywords in every line of your logs list:

```
for line in logs:
    for word in keywords:
        if word in line:
            print ("ALERT")
```

You can easily modify this to also print the line and the keyword along with the alert. You'll be iterating over 20 character-capped lines (a video-game chat-log by the looks of it), and you'll be checking for a dozen or two keywords. The runtime for this is quite low - despite the nested for-loop implementation. However, this solution falls apart if your logs file is **very** large.